# Android - Segmented Circle Buttons

Tags: android, button, geometry

I'm trying to create a button which looks something like this:

[image: sAMPLE]

With each third acting as a separate button.  I'm looking for advice on how to implement this.  I've read a few posts about circular buttons, but this is a slightly different issue, as the buttons themselves are rather irregular shapes.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The size is fixed or do you expect the shape to have dynamic dimensions based on screen size, density?

Comment: I'm building for two different phones specifically.  I can do hard coded xml's for them.  I know for a fact the program will never be used for anything other than these two phone sizes.  One qualifies as large, the other is a small screen.  Dyncamic is great, but not totally needed.

Comment: You aren't going to be able to do those as buttons, in terms of using `Button` or `ImageButton`, as they both assume a square click area. However, you could draw your pie chart using 2D graphics (`Canvas`, etc.) and manage the touch events yourself to detect taps upon them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create a [Custom View](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html), as @CommonsWare hinted at.  That document covers everything, but basically you'll render that image into a Canvas (fill the square, draw the circle, draw the three lines, then draw the text) and detect touch events yourself, doing a little math to figure out which segment was pressed.  Android makes this surprisingly easy.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't do exactly what this guide said, but you pointed me in the right direction.  Accepted as answer.